# Internal React error Attempted to capture a commit phase error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

```
const [ingreitem, setingreitem] = useState([]);
var ingi = [];
const filterIt = (params) => {
for (let index = 0; index < ingreitem.length; index++) {
const element = ingreitem[index];
if (element["category"] === params ||element["location"] === params ||element["confection"] === params) {
ingi.push(element);
}

console.log(ingreitem)
setingreitem(ingi);
console.log(ingreitem)
};
```

`LOG  \[{"category": "Juice", "confection": "Fresh", "expiry": "30-8-2025", "location": "Frige", "name": "mango juice"}, {"category": "Food", "confection": "Confection", "expiry": "29-8-2023", "location": "Frige", "name": "Mayoneese"}\] LOG  \[{"category": "Juice", "confection": "Fresh", "expiry": "30-8-2025", "location": "Frige", "name": "mango juice"}, {"category": "Oil", "confectio29-8-2023", "location": "Frige", "name": "Mayoneese"}, {"category": "Catagory", "confection": "Confection", "expiry": "29-8-2023", "location": "Location", "name": "Name"}\] LOG  \[{"category": "Juice", "confection": "Fresh", "expiry": "30-8-2025", "location": "Frige", "name": "mango juice"}, {"category": "Oil", "confection": "Fresh", "expiry": "28-8-2028", "location": "Cubord", "name": "Almond oil"}, {"category": "Pickle", "confection": "Preserved", "expiry": "28-8-2025", "location": "Jar", "name": "Onian pickle"}, {"category": "Food", "confection": "Confection", "expiry": "29-8-2023", "location": "Frige", "name": "Mayoneese"}, {"category": "Catagory", "confection": "Confection", "expiry": "29-8-2023", "location": "Location", "name": "Name"}\] ERROR  Warning: Internal React error: Attempted to capture a commit phase error inside a detached tree. This indicates a bug in React. Likely causes include deleting the same fiber more than once, committing an already-finished tree, or an inconsistent return pointer.`

***Error message:***

TypeError: destroy is not a function (it is Object)
in Unknown

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.